# Unable to query multiple salesforce object usnig Mule Soft Anypoint

Tags: salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I am new to SalesForce as well as Mule Anypoint and I have this task of getting data from multiple SalesForce objects into relational DB.

These are my SalesForce queries that I need. Basically, For every lead I get I need to perform the queries below to get the contact_guid__c

```
select ownerid from lead where id = ‘<lead_id>'
select EmployeeNumber from user where id = ‘<ownerid>'
select contact_guid__c from contact where Employee_Number__c = ‘<EmployeeNumber>'
```

I don't know how to go about combining these queries in such a way that I can integrate it into Mule workflow. 
I tried the following method (See screenshot) but it didn't work at all. 
[image]

The For Each workflow takes the ownerid and makes the second call to query EmployeeNumber from user table.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you querying in SFA or DB? SFA require JSON Object. You can use MEL to formulate the expressions and in DB are well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you query DB, you can use multiple IDs in `where` clause in Salesforce SOQL query.  Refer to the following for SOQL to use in Mule:
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf

By this way, you can reduce your number of calls from Mule to Salesforce.

Regarding flow changes, you need to first see whether `FOR` loop is required (if your `WHERE IN` clause in SOQL will be sufficient) and then you can call Salesforce thrice (3 message processors of Salesforce).